# flutter: best way to implement inner navigation with bottom nav bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-navigation

I'm developing a flutter application and I'm now struggling to understand what is the best way to implement a complex bottom bar navigation.
Here are my requirements:

- each button on the nav bar should lead to a different section
- each section should be able to have multiple screens inside of it
- user can navigate from any page of a section to any page in another section and back
- each section should show the last visited page if we come back to it

for example, let's say we have two sections, each made of two pages: `SectionOneA`, `SectionOneB`, `SectionTwoA`, `SectionTwoB`.

A few use cases:

- user navigates from `SectionOneB` to `SectionTwoB` by pressing a button inside `SectionOneB`, when user presses back (on android) from `SectionTwoB`, we should navigate back to `SectionOneB`
- user navigates to `SectionTwoA` by the nav bar, then navigates to `SectionTwoB` via a button in `SectionTwoA`, then navigates to `SectionOneA` via the nav bar and then press the `SectionTwo` icon in the nav bar again. we should show `SectionTwoB`. if back is pressed we should navigate to `SectionTwoA`.

in both these examples, when moving from one section to another, the correct nav bar item should be highlighted.

I'm new to flutter so I'm learning as I go. For now, what I've done is using nav bar with `PageViewer` to switch from section to section, then each section uses a `PageViewer` to handle switching from page to page. This worked well until I had to implement the first usecase above, at this point it seems to me that it would be quite challenging to implment a proper navigation stack as demanded by the usecase and I feel it would be better to rethink the whole thing, only I've no idea what is the best way to approach this.
A temporary solution would be to also include `SectionTwoB` in the `PageViewer` of section one, but that would not allow me to highlight the proper nav bar item.

Any lead on how to approach this? All the examples I find seems too simple and/or I'm failing at understanding how to connect the pieces together. I'm using flutter_bloc as a state management library.

Comment: @Dude agreed, but it would not be possible to put all related code here, neither produce a minimal example. also, I believe the I've written now doesn't have any particular problem per se, but rather goes in wrong direction on how to solve the problem, so what would be the point of putting it here? Answers may be opinion based, but they could still be helpful.

Comment: I would recommend using a routing package to handle these scenarios.
See [qlevar_router](https://github.com/SchabanBo/qlevar_router) and [this example](https://github.com/SchabanBo/qr_samples#bottom-navigation-bar).